# Redirecting to a Master Details page in xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

my aim is to set the main mage as my master page after a successfully login.
This is my code--

```
MasterDetailPage masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage
                {
                    Master = new partialMasterPageJobseeker(),
                    Detail = new NavigationPage(new Jobsearch()),
                };
                Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
```

in ios it's working fine but in android i am getting an error -

```
No view found for id 0x1  xamarin form
```

please help me what should i do now?

Comment: Are you using any custom renderers?

Comment: no..normal master details page

Comment: what is your page? is it Xamarin.forms or Xamarin.android?

Answer (score 0):

//You need to assign the "Title" property try this:

```
MasterDetailPage masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage
                {
                   Title="xx",
                    Master = new partialMasterPageJobseeker(),
                    Detail = new NavigationPage(new Jobsearch()),
                };
                Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
```